# RUN command in dockerfile will execute while container starts up?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and am being confused by RUN cmd.

> RUN  echo YYYYYYYYYY && yum install -y gcc

The RUN will be executed while docker build and docker run.
But it seems that the echo will run only in build process. So I could not see echo output YYYYYYYYYY after issuing docker run, and can only see output of yum.

Why the echo is not executed while container starts up?

Comment: RUN commands are only executed on image creation (docker build), but not in container start (docker run). That's the difference between RUN and CMD (among other things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RUN command is executed ONLY when creating an *image* with **docker build**. Your run will make and *echo* (for logging) and install gcc in the *image*

If you want to execute when the *container* starts, you must use **CMD** or **ENTRYPOINT**.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was misled by another yum call in the CMD script.